# Add a form to Flask-Admin list view

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-admin

I am trying to pass a form to my `list_view` in a Flask-Admin app. I have the following code

```
class MarketRowView(ModelView):
    list_template = 'marketrowdata-list.html'

    @expose('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def list_view(self):
            form = MarketValueForm(request.form)
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                    link = form.link
                    process_link(link)
            self._template_args['form'] = form
            return super(MarketRowView, self).list_view()

    def is_accessible(self):
            return login.current_user.is_authenticated()
```

the thing is my template doesnt "sees" the form, i.e, `form` is a `NoneType` object. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I tried to replace

```
self._template_args['form'] = form
return super(MarketRowView, self).list_view()
```

by

```
return self.render('marketrowdata-list.html', form=form)
```

and now the form renders well, but the table with the content of my objects at the database its not appearing. I think that probably its rendering the `AdminIndexView`.